# Кнопка "гамбургер" меню

Tags: html

Пытаюсь сделать кнопку-гамбургер для меню, нашел очень легкий способ в одну строку html, но не понимаю как привязать меню к кнопке.

```js
    document.querySelector( "#nav-toggle" )
      .addEventListener( "click", function() {
        this.classList.toggle( "active" );
      });
```

```css
    #nav-toggle span, #nav-toggle span:before, #nav-toggle span:after {
      cursor: pointer;
      float: right;
      border-radius: 1px;
      height: 5px;
      width: 35px;
      background: black;
      position: absolute;
      display: block;
      content: '';
    }
    #nav-toggle span:before {
      top: -10px;
    }
    #nav-toggle span:after {
      bottom: -10px; 
    }
```

```html
<a id="nav-toggle" href="#"><span></span></a>
```

Comment: эта строка бесполезна чуть более, чем полностью, ибо вырвана из контекста и у вас не заработает просто так. почитайте про `navbar` в `bootstrap`, например, там хорошая реализация того, что вы ищете. одним `html` тут никак не обойтись

Comment: тут не один html, тут сss и javascript http://codepen.io/elijahmanor/pen/Igpoe

Comment: @EdgarKiljak а почему мы их не видим?

Comment: @EdgarKiljak Обновите вопрос и допишите туда код js и css